# Multiple Datepicker Popup using bootstrap AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm new to AngularJS.

I'm using angular 1.5.x and ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js.
I want to use multiple datepicker popup on page(around 6-7). Example provided [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepickerPopup) 
specifically mentions each popup. Is there a generic way of handling this?

I'm not using JQuery.
Thanks

Comment: have you tried just putting a bunch of inputs on the page? <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="first">, etc??? just change the model

Comment: Yes i did. How about handling of ng-click="open1()" and is-open="popup1.opened". Do i need to mention this for all datepicker..

Comment: Well I suppose it depends on what you need to do. If you want something to happen other than a model value to be updated, you can definitely have an ng-click defined. maybe a plunkr would help

Comment: Are you asking about, for instance, `$scope.open1 = function() {$scope.popup1.opened = true;};`?

Comment: Yes, do i need to mention it for each popup. Can it be handled dynamically?

Comment: Try passing it as a parameter to a generic open function.